# Magento 2 Image in product detail not showing

Tags: magento2, category-products

I have created many products manually and uploaded images to them, only in list is showing the image, but when I click on product to see the details it's not showing.

[image]

I have run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

chmod -R 775 magento_folder
```

It's not working.
Only in this store view is not working, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the page_cache, view_preprocessed, and pub/static/frontend directories

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
rm -rf var/page_cache
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
```

then run setup:static-content:deploy again, and cache:clean again

Comment: Still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Open product in you admin and check for image **Base** Role assigned to image or not?

[image]

If that is not assigned, please set Base role there and save product and clean cache and check.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Yes it's assigned, it has the 4 labels Base, Small, Swatch and Thumbnail

Comment: Hi @krishan can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327438/magento-2-how-to-display-shipping-methods-sort-order-by-price?noredirect=1#

Comment: Hi @krishna can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330734/magento2-customer-multi-select-attribute-issue